# List vendors, and lowest priced product SQL

Tags: sql, inner-join, min

I am trying to join 2 tables and create a new field returning the lowest value of a product. I've tried many variations and can't seem to get it to work.

```
SELECT DISTINCT VENDOR.*, PRODUCT.P_PRICE, PRODUCT.LOWEST_PRICE AS MIN(PRODUCT.P_PRICE)
FROM PRODUCT
INNER JOIN VENDOR
ON VENDOR.V_CODE = PRODUCT.V_CODE
ORDER BY VENDOR.V_NAME
```

Comment: PRODUCT.LOWEST_PRICE AS MIN(PRODUCT.P_PRICE) looks wrong. Try MIN(PRODUCT.P_PRICE) AS LOWEST_PRICE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this, This will order from Minimum price vendor product

```
SELECT  VENDOR.V_NAME,  MIN(PRODUCT.P_PRICE) AS LOWEST_PRICE 
FROM VENDOR
INNER JOIN PRODUCT
ON VENDOR.V_CODE = PRODUCT.V_CODE
GROUP BY VENDOR.V_NAME
ORDER BY LOWEST_PRICE
```

**SQL FIDDLE:**- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/467c8/2

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the lowest price by vendor, use group by and min:

```
SELECT  VENDOR.V_NAME,  MIN(PRODUCT.P_PRICE) AS LOWEST_PRICE 
FROM PRODUCT
INNER JOIN VENDOR
ON VENDOR.V_CODE = PRODUCT.V_CODE
GROUP BY VENDOR.V_NAME
ORDER BY VENDOR.V_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing how your schema is defined try this:

```
SELECT 
    VENDOR.V_NAME, 
    PRODUCT.P_PRICE AS [VENDOR PRICE], 
    MIN(PRODUCT.P_PRICE) AS [LOWEST PRICE]
FROM 
    PRODUCT 
    INNER JOIN VENDOR ON VENDOR.V_CODE = PRODUCT.V_CODE 
GROUP BY
    VENDOR.V_NAME,PRODUCT.P_PRICE
ORDER BY 
    VENDOR.V_NAME
```

Comment: Cut a quick paste of original code, fixed it, didn't catch it

Comment: Additionally, your brackets assume sql server, but its not tagged as such.

Comment: My French is poor, but I think the saying is touche'. Yet another assumption by myself. lol

Comment: Because he had both listed I assumed he might want a list of all vendors and their prices and a listing against the lowest price offered by all vendors offering the price. If is simply just who has the lowest price then it is obviously a listing without a price comparison.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the lowest price product per vendor, I would suggest using window functions:

```
select pv.*
from (select v.v_name, p.p_name, p.p_price
             row_number() over (partition by p.v_code order by p.p_price asc) as seqnum
      from vendor v join
           product p
           on v.v_code = p.v_code
     ) pv
where seqnum = 1
```